# How can I count the number of cities per country from the data file?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, filereader

How can I count the number of cities per country from the data file? I would also like to display the value as percentage of the total.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;

public class city
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] city = new String[120]; 
        String country = null;
        String[] latDegree =new String[120];
        String lonDegree =null;
        String latMinute =null;
        String lonMinute =null;
        String latDir = null;
        String lonDir = null;
        String time = null;
        String amORpm = null;

        try 
        {
            File myFile = new File("CityLongandLat.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(myFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = null;

            int position =0;    
            int latitude=0;
            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // System.out.println(line);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");

                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    city[position] = st.nextToken();
                    country = st.nextToken();
                    latDegree[latitude] =st.nextToken();
                    latMinute =st.nextToken();
                    latDir = st.nextToken();
                    lonDegree =st.nextToken();
                    lonMinute =st.nextToken();
                    lonDir = st.nextToken();
                    time = st.nextToken();
                    amORpm = st.nextToken();
                }

                if(city.length<8)
                {
                    System.out.print(city[position] + "\t\t");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(city[position] + "\t");
                } 

                if(country.length()<16)
                {
                    System.out.print(country +"\t\t");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(country);
                } 

                System.out.print(latDegree + "\t");
                System.out.print(latMinute + "\t");
                System.out.print(latDir + "\t");
                System.out.print(lonDegree + "\t");
                System.out.print(lonMinute + "\t");
                System.out.print(lonDir + "\t");
                System.out.print(time + "\t");
                System.out.println(amORpm + "\t");

                position++;
            }

            br.close();

        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error !!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of how the data would be laid out in the text file?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Yes. Realized.  `City vs Country`  :)

Comment: i need to count the number of cities from the data file which matches each country do you know how to do that @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: int m = city[0].length();
        int position = 0;
        
        for(int k = 0; k<city.length; k++)
        {
            System.out.println("k= "+k+"  "+city[k].length()+" "+city[k]);
          if(city[k].length()>m)
          {
              m = city[k].length();
              position = k;
          }  @PakkuDon@MartijnCourteaux@SURESHATTA
        }

Comment: @user3135233 A Simple Suggestion close your `BufferedReader br` in the `finally{}` block.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you need not to count I guess. You need a Map. Where Country as a key and cities as a value of List. While reading place values in Map and use the sizes. Search in that way.

Comment: the text file is excel spreadsheet

Comment: what code could i use to solve this problem

Comment: not sure what you mean by map @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: Show some of your text file and what you wish to do with the data

Comment: And also, what's not working about your current code.

Comment: everything is working with the code the file is read by buffered reader and is diplaying the latitude and other information and also have the program displaying largest city in terms of name @peeskillet

Comment: Aberdeen Scotland  57 2 [Ljava.lang.String;@33906773 9 N [Ljava.lang.String;@4d77c977 9 W 05:00 p.m. 
Adelaide Australia  34 138 [Ljava.lang.String;@33906773 55 S [Ljava.lang.String;@4d77c977 36 E 02:30 a.m. 
Algiers Algeria  36 3 [Ljava.lang.String;@33906773 50 N [Ljava.lang.String;@4d77c977 0 E 06:00 p.m. 
[Ljava.lang.String;@33906773 25 N [Ljava.lang.String;@4d77c977 55 W 05:00 p.m.@peeskillet

Comment: here are some of the output from the data file from my programme @peeskillet

Answer (score 0):

> *"here are some of the output from the data file from my programme"*
>
> `Aberdeen Scotland 57 2 [Ljava.lang.String;@33906773 9 N [Ljava.lang.String;@4d7‌​7c977 9 W 05:00 p.m. Adelaide Australia 34 138 [Ljava.lang.String;@33906773 55 S [Ljava.lang.String;‌​@4d77c977 36 E 02:30 a.m...`

The reason why your getting that output, is because you're trying to print the array object `latDegree`.

```
String[] latDegree
...
System.out.print(latDegree + "\t");
```

Also, you have `lattitude = 0;` but you never increment it, so it will always use the index 0 for the array. You need to increment it, like you did `position++`.

So for the print statement, print the print the value at index `lattitude`, not the entire array

Try this

```
System.out.print(latDegree[lattitude] + "\t");

...

lattitude++;
```

If for some reason you *do* want to print the array, then use `Arrays.toString(array);` or just iterate through it

Answer (score 0):

One easy way that comes to my mind would be as follows...

Create a hashMap Object where the key is a string (the country) and the value is an integer (number of cities found for the country) so it would be something like

Map countryResultsFoundMap = new HashMap< String,Integer>();

In short, for each row you would pick the country, (I would recommend that you .trim() and .toLowerCase() the value first) and check if it is existing in the hashMap, if not, add the entry like countryResultsFoundMap.put(country,0), otherwise, if the country already exists the pick the value from the hashMAp and add +1  to its integer value.

Eventually you will have all the values stored in the map and you can have access to that data for your calculations.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I would also start with a map, and group the cities by country with a map.

```
Map<String,<List<String>>
```

Where the key is the country and the value is the list of cities in this country. With the size() methods you can perform the operations cities per country and percentage of total.

When you read one line you check if the key (country) already exists, if not you create a new list and add the city, otherwise add the city only to the existing list.

As a starter you could use the following snippet. However this sample assumes that the content of the file is read already and given as an argument to the method.

```
Map<String,List<String>> groupByCountry(List<String> lines){

    Map<String,List<String>> group = new HashMap<>();

    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
        String city = tokens[0];
        String country = tokens[1];
        ...
        if(group.containsKey(country)){
            group.get(country).add(city);
        }else{
            List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
            cities.add(city);
            group.put(country, cities);
        }
    }

    return group;
}
```

Comment: not sure what code to used for this method can you give me more information thanks @Spindizzy

Comment: I added a short sample for more information. Hope that helps.